# Line return in D3.js in a mouseover event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to structure my output in D3.js visualization and I am using \n line returns
but it's not read by JS, any ideas on how it can be solved?

Thank you very much in advance :)

```
.on('mousemove', function(d) {
    tooltip
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 10 + 'px')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px')
      .text(`Number of clones in the class: ${d.data.value/2}   \r\n \n \r
             Code of the class: ${d.data.code}
             Lines at which the clone appears:  ${d.data.lines}`);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tspan` for each new line and play with `dy` attributes for line height

```
.on('mousemove', function(d) {
    tooltip
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 10 + 'px')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px')
      .html(`<tspan x='0' dy='1.2em'>Number of clones in the class: ${d.data.value/2}</tspan>
             <tspan x='0' dy='1.2em'>Code of the class: ${d.data.code}</tspan>
            <tspan x='0' dy='1.2em'>Lines at which the clone appears:  ${d.data.lines}</tspan>`);
    })
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked!, I used <br> </br>